# Making np.loadtxt work with multiple possible delimiters

Tags: python, numpy

I have a program that reads in data files and the user selects which column they want to use. I want it to be more universal with input files; sometimes, columns can look like this:

```
10:34:24.58  8.284  6.121
```

And sometimes they can look like this:

```
10 34 24.58  8.284  6.121
```

I want the program to recognize this as 5 columns in BOTH cases, instead of 5 columns for the first and 3 for the second. Basically, I want it to recognize `white space` as a delimiter and `:` as a delimiter as well.

Is there a simple way to do this? I know numpy takes a delimiter command, but as far as I'm aware it can only use one.

Comment: If you don't mind using `pandas`, its `read_csv` function (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has a `sep` argument that can be a regular expression.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the answer above, but I believe I've found a workaround that allows for a simple two-line solution, without modifying the rest of my program.

The initial loadtxt line looked like this:

```
import numpy as np
...
data = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=header,dtype=str)
```

By utilizing StringIO, we can simply read the file and replace every instance of `':'` with `" "`, without having to modify any of the other code.

```
import numpy as np
import StringIO
...
s = open(filename).read().replace(':',' ')
data = np.loadtxt(StringIO.StringIO(s),skiprows=header,dtype=str)
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: For anyone who might be trying to use this method, please note that module StringIO is no longer available in Python 3. Instead, import the io module and use io.StringIO or io.BytesIO for text and data respectively. More info: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 5):

`np.loadtxt` (and `genfromtxt`) accept any iterable as input as long as it feeds it one line at a time.  So the lines of your file can be passed through a function or generator that massages it in various ways.  Here's a simple example

Define a pair of lines that simulates your file:

```
In [7]: txt="""10:34:24.58  8.284  6.121
   ...: 10 34 24.58  8.284  6.121
   ...: """

In [8]: txt=txt.splitlines()

In [9]: txt
Out[9]: ['10:34:24.58  8.284  6.121', '10 34 24.58  8.284  6.121']
```

If it weren't for the `:` I could pass this directly to `loadtxt`.

But let's pass the lines through a generator that replaces the ':' with a space.  It could be a function (with yield).  Here I'm using one of those new-fangled generator comprehension expressions:

```
In [10]: np.loadtxt((x.replace(b':',b' ') for x in txt))
Out[10]: 
array([[ 10.   ,  34.   ,  24.58 ,   8.284,   6.121],
       [ 10.   ,  34.   ,  24.58 ,   8.284,   6.121]])
```

with a file, this should work (iterating on an open file returns lines):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    A=np.loadtxt((x.replace(b':',b' ') for x in f))
```

regex would be useful for more elaborate replacements.

Comment: Cool, thanks for this! Now, I'm pretty new to Python, so would you be able to tell me how to combine this with my current loadtxt command: `data = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=header,dtype=str)`

Comment: I would expand the generator expression into a generator function, and have that take care of skipping rows as needed.  That kind of use of generator or filter with `load/gen` has been discussed in earlier SO questions.